# Can anyone direct me on how to got to

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, image-classification, preprocessing

I am a newbie to python.

I have uploaded about 2000 images into my google drive, assigned a variable to all content in the folder and tried to split the folder's content into training and testing, but it kept bringing error. Can anyone direct me on how to get to splitting the data stage?

Comment: what exact error, what are your configs, what did you exactly do...